# \setcaptionfont in tufte-book does not work

Tags: captions, tufte

I want to format all my captions (tables, figures, ...) in tufte-book. The built-in \setcaptionfont command leads to surprising results: margin tables are all formatted, captions of normal tables or figures not at all. Am I the only one...? I use Lyx 2.3.

```
%% LyX 2.3.0 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[ngerman,nohyper]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\synctex=-1
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=1,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\setcaptionfont{%
  \color{red}
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{margintable}
Red table

\caption{Red caption}
\end{margintable}

\lipsum[5]

\begin{figure}
Black text

\caption{Black Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The solution to the `figure` caption

You specified `nohyper` as your class option but then loaded the `hyperref` package anyway. Removing the `hyperref` package solves your problem. Just tell LyX not to load `hyperref`, and please consider using `utf8` for input encoding and specify a language for `babel`.

**Added**: If you *do* want to load `hyperref`, then just remove the class option `nohyper` (`tufte-book` loads `hyperref` by default).

```
\documentclass[ngerman,nohyper]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% utf8 is better than latin9
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{babel}% What language?
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setcaptionfont{%
  \color{red}
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{margintable}
Red table
\caption{Red caption}
\end{margintable}

\lipsum[5]

\begin{figure}
Black text
\caption{Black Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Figure caption color fixed]

## The problem with `\setcaptionfont`

As you mentioned in the comments below, the `margintable` contents are colored as well, which is undesired.

**But I’m afraid this is by design** (or perhaps a bug?).

The definition of `\setcaptionfont` is found in [`tufte-common.def`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex):

```
\newcommand*{\setcaptionfont}[1]{\renewcommand*{\@tufte@caption@font}{#1}}
```

which calls the internal command `\@tufte@caption@font`.

When `\@tufte@caption@font` is used in the “margin float environment”, on which `marginfigure` and `margintable` are based, it influences the whole float:

```
\newenvironment{@tufte@margin@float}[2][-1.2ex]%
  {\FloatBarrier% process all floats before this point so the figure/table numbers stay in order.
  \begin{lrbox}{\@tufte@margin@floatbox}%
  \begin{minipage}{\marginparwidth}%
    \@tufte@caption@font% <-- Your customized style is applied to the whole minipage
    \def\@captype{#2}%
    \hbox{}\vspace*{#1}%
    \@tufte@caption@justification%
    \@tufte@margin@par%
    \noindent%
  }
  {\end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \marginpar{\usebox{\@tufte@margin@floatbox}}%
  }
```

So, in the minds of the designers of `tufte-book`, you’re supposed to put *only caption text in the margin note position*. Well, except for graphics, and of course they are *not* affected by the font changing commands.

From a typographic point of view, I’d agree that you should *never* put tables in the margin note position (tables belong to the body text). If you insist, then there’s a workaround:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,nohyper]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% utf8 is better than latin9
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{babel}% What language?
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setcaptionfont{%
  \color{red}
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Define a font style switch for better coding.
% Add the following line to LyX: Document -> Settings -> LaTeX Preamble
\newcommand*\restoremarginfontstyle{\color{black}}

\begin{document}
\begin{margintable}
\begingroup% <-- Need to be inserted by Ctrl+L in LyX
\restoremarginfontstyle% <-- Switch used here, need to be inserted by Ctrl+L in LyX
Red table? Now black!
\endgroup% <-- Need to be inserted by Ctrl+L in LyX
\caption{Red caption}
\end{margintable}

\lipsum[5]

\begin{figure}
Black text
\caption{Black caption? Now red!}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Fixed workaround]

I don’t recommend doing this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the package clash was indeed responsible for the second caption not being red -- but what about the "Red Table" still being red?? Even if I remove the caption completely, all margin content is formatted. :-(

Comment: @TimEisenhardt Did you mean “margin content is still colored” when you say “all margin content is formatted”

Comment: @TimEisenhardt Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I use margin tables to convey additional examples such as densities of typical materials -- IMO this need not interrupt the explanation in the body text.

And of course I don't want red captions, I only want them to be the same size as footnotes. Never thought it would be that hard...

Comment: @TimEisenhardt You’re welcome! An additional note: If you want the captions to be the same size as footnotes, then the default setting of `\@tufte@marginfont` suffices (which is `\normalfont\footnotesize\sffamily` or `\normalfont\footnotesize`), so you don’t need to modify anything. By doing `\setcaptionfont{\color{red}}` you are actually overwriting the command to use body text font size for the captions.